# Why is wordpress text missing at some parts?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, authentication

For example my wp login page doesn't show text

http://www.laserqueen.cl/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.laserqueen.cl%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Same happens with some parts in the admin panel, even while trying to upload images, etc.

There is a warnning I am getting too:

PHP Warning:  substr_count(): Empty substring in /home/cla35334/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 319

¿This could be because of some missing file?

The page is simple, a stactic one, the only thing I did was to upload the wp files from one server to another (in the first one, everything was working fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always check if any plugin is making this problem, can you first check that? Or updating the permalinks?

If that doesn't work, try using [Wp-Clone](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/) install in the old server to the new one and that won't give you any problem.